# How to check in array whether value in array exist and if does take the corresponding data to process

Tags: php

I'm stuck with sorting my array to taking out unique values and process the associated value to an accumulative value.

Source code :

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
$row1[8] = $row1[8] / 60;
 echo    "<tr>".
         "<td>".$row1[0]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[1]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[2]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[3]           . "</td>".        
         "<td>".$row1[4]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[5]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[6]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[7]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[8]           . "</td>".
         "<td>".$row1[9]           . "</td>";
         $counters = array();
         $counters[$row1[9]] += $row1[8];
         arsort($counters);
        var_dump($counters);
```

The var dump is as such :

```
array(1) { ["derek"]=> int(2) } 
array(1) { ["garyhui"]=> float(0.5) } 
array(1) { ["nikole"]=> int(1) } 
array(1) { ["tony"]=> int(4) } 
array(1) { ["tony"]=> int(2) } 
array(1) { ["tony"]=> float(3.5) } 
array(1) { ["tony"]=> float(2.5) }
```

I need the end result to be smth similar like

```
Derek : 2
Garyhui : 0.5
Nikole : 1
```

Tony : 12 <-- note this number was able to accumulate on its own based on the previous array indexs association. Appreciate any help given !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep redefining $counters to empty array, because you keep doing `$counters = array()` inside the loop. That's why they don't add up. You have to remove that single line of code and move it to somewhere above the loop. Exactly like this:

```
$counters = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
    $row1[8] = $row1[8] / 60;
     echo    "<tr>".
     "<td>".$row1[0]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[1]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[2]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[3]           . "</td>".        
     "<td>".$row1[4]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[5]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[6]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[7]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[8]           . "</td>".
     "<td>".$row1[9]           . "</td>";
     $counters[$row1[9]] += $row1[8];
     arsort($counters);
    var_dump($counters);
```

Comment: Thanks it solved ! Btw i keep getting undefined index notice error. Any way to circumvent it ? Really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

Use **[array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists)** to check for existing key value:

```
#like @Erik said, place this out of while loop,
#keeping it inside while makes it empty in every loop
$counters = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{ 
  /*
     Your echo code here
  */

  if(array_key_exists($row1[9],$counters)){
     #if exists, accumulate value of current key
     $counters[$row1[9]] += $row1[8];
  }
  else
  {
     #if does not exist, create new key
     $counters[$row1[9]] = $row1[8]; 
  }
}
```